# Location animation using blue flashing arrow and show direction in Android Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps

How can I animate location displaying animation using blue flashing arrow and showing direction as animated in Android Google Map? I searched but can't find appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

For you location you could just use a flashing blue arrow `.png` as the icon element.

As for the animated direction, AFAIK this is not possible in the current version of Google Map API V2.

Comment: yes now I downloaded the arrow and I can show arrow. But how to animate flashing blue color?

Comment: your image should be animated before you add it to map, you can't animate it from inside the app. but use an animated .png.

Comment: well I didn't try it, and it may not work. but you can try: http://www.truekolor.net/learn-how-to-create-an-animated-png/